# Qt video capture doesn't work on Windows. Options?

Tags: windows, qt, video

In our Qt application we need to capture video from a webcam. Our application is cross platform (Mac, Windows, Linux).

With Qt 5 it was supposed to be easy following the new feature added to Qt Multilmedia.
However, as it turns out this is not working for Windows platform and is a known bug:

https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-30541

It works fine on Mac BTW.
I don't understand how do they release a major new feature with no support for Windows.
There is no ETA for the bug fix.

So, what are the options to go around it? using OpenCV immediately comes to mind. Any other options?

Answer (score 0):

Try the Qt Media Encoding Library for that - http://kibsoft.ru

Answer (score 0):

Qt wrapper for libvlc [VLC-Qt Library](http://projects.tano.si/vlc-qt/)